# How to bind dictionary key with the listbox textblock?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've got a problem get binding working in an DataTemplate of a ListView. My binding target is a KeyValuePair.

this is MY XAML Code:-

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Setting" ItemsSource="{Binding DictTemperature}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="582" Width="300">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="78">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image x:Name="Img_ListSetting" Width="50" Height="50" Source="/Assets/un-checked.png" Margin="18,7,507,21" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Tb_ListSetting" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" FontFamily="OpenSans" FontSize="30" Margin="89,0,18,20" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Line_ListSetting" Height="1" Margin="15,66,15,11" Fill="#FF3498DB"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And This is My C# Code :-

```
public Dictionary<string, bool> DictTemperature { set; get; }
DictTemperature = new Dictionary<string, bool>();


        if (!appSettings.Contains("AppTemperature"))
        {
            DictTemperature.Add("Celsius", true);
            DictTemperature.Add("Fahrenheit", true);
            DictTemperature.Add("Kelvin", true);
            DictTemperature.Add("Rankine", true);
            appSettings.Add("AppTemperature", DictTemperature);


        }
        DictTemperature = (Dictionary<string, bool>)appSettings["AppTemperature"];
```

here listbox is showing count as 4 and showing the key value pairs also but unable to bind key with the textblock.
Please tell me the solution....

Comment: the code should work. can you check the parent of listview? may be the container is hidden or its width/height is set to 0!

Can you share the whole page(xaml) code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334128/binding-a-dictionarys-key-and-value-in-a-listbox-with-wpf) (Binding a Dictionary's key and value in a listbox with wpf)